# How to make a custom UIPageControl with cicles instead of dots

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want page Control with circles how to do this i have using A page Control now but it has dots instead of circles

Answer (score 2):

you have to create custom page scroll. for this you should refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865296/custom-uipagecontrol-view-replacing-dots-with-page-x-of-y). hope you will get idea.

also some useful links :

(1) http://www.onidev.com/2009/12/02/customisable-uipagecontrol/

(2) http://worldlinkdevteam.motionforum.net/t10-designing-custom-uipagecontrol